# Unable to upload a image ; laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, image, validation

I'm a new to Laravel and using Laravel6.0. While doing validation I'm getting a error.

> **The picture must be an image. The picture must be a file. The picture must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif.**

I'm searching a solution on google, but cannot find correct an answer.

I added dd(request) in my rules() ,but I got the same error.

This is my ContentController, ContentRequest and create.blade.php.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
     <form action="{{route('content.store')}}" method="post"　enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">タイトル</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="旅のタイトル" name="title" value="{{old('title')}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">大陸名</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="continent"  value="{{old('continent')}}">
            <option>アジア</option>
            <option>北アメリカ</option>
            <option>中南米</option>
            <option>ヨーロッパ</option>
            <option>アフリカ</option>
            <option>オセアニア</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">国名</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="日本" name="country" value="{{old('country')}}">       
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">滞在期間</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="span" placeholder="滞在期間を選択"  >
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
          　<option>12</option>
          　<option>13</option>
          　<option>14</option>
          　<option>15</option>
          　<option>16</option>
          　<option>17</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">費用</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="costs" placeholder="金額を選択" value='{{old('costs')}}'>
            <option>10000</option>
            <option>30000</option>
            <option>50000</option>
            <option>70000</option>
            <option>100000</option>
            <option>150000</option>
            <option>200000</option>
            <option>250000</option>
            <option>300000</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">写真</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="picture" value="{{old('picture')}}">
          <div class="input-group-append">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary reset"><i class="fas fa-times fa-fw"></i>取消</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">コンテンツ</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" name="content"  >{{old('content')}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">投稿</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

```
ContentRequest

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_id'=>'required',
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'continent' => 'required|string',
            'picture'=>'required|image|max:1000',
            'country' => 'required|string',
            'costs'=>'required|numeric',
            'span'=>'required|numeric',
            'content'=>'required|string|max:250',
        ];

        
         
    }
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ContentRequest;
use App\Content;

class ContentController extends Controller

  public function store(ContentRequest $request)
    {
        if($request->validated()){
            $content =new Content;
            
            $filename = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');
            $content->picture = basename($filename);

            $content->user_id = $request->user_id;
            $content->content = $request->content;
            $content->title = $request->title;
            $content->span = $request->span;
            $content->continent = $request->continent;
            $content->country = $request-> country;
            $content->costs = $request->costs;
            
            $content->save();
        }
        
        return redirect('/');
        
    }
```

Comment: `image` implies `file` and `mimes:jpeg,png,bmp,gif,svg,webp` so you don't need those two (unless you want to restrict the mime types). But to clarify. You are saying you are posting an image using the shared form and still getting the validation error?

Comment: I see. thanks.  right, I'm saying I am getting the validation error even if i post an image using the shared form .
The picture must be an image.

Comment: I think the error is on your request, whats the output of `dd($request->all());`??  Check if you may have forgotten to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form

Comment: Check the browser network tab (you might need to somehow preserve the log) to ensure the image is being sent in the request and also add a `dd(request()->files)` in your `rules()` method before the return to check if it's being correctly received. In some rare cases certain webserver rewrite rules might strip out post data

Comment: I got the same error and I already add enctype="multipart/form-data" in create.blade.php.

Comment: I added a **dd(request()->files) ** in my **rules()**, but I got the same.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'user_id'=>'required',
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'continent' => 'required|string',
            'picture'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:1000',
            'country' => 'required|string',
            'costs'=>'required|numeric',
            'span'=>'required|numeric',
            'content'=>'required|string|max:250',
        ];
    }
```

and in the store function

```
if($request->validated()){

            $content =new Content;
            
            $filename = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');
            $content->picture = basename($filename);

            $content->user_id = $request->user_id;
            $content->content = $request->content;
            $content->title = $request->title;
            $content->span = $request->span;
            $content->continent = $request->continent;
            $content->country = $request-> country;
            $content->costs = $request->costs;
            
            $content->save();
        }
```

Comment: The picture must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif.

Comment: you should change if condition in store() function as if($request->validated()){}

Comment: because your image validation is already done by ContentRequest Class you will not use isValid() method for an image in store function you just need to validate the request

Comment: I add dd(request()->files) in my rules() ,but i got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
'picture' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1000',
```